# Thrift TNonblockingServer.cpp Undeclared Identifier - Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, build, compiler-errors, thrift

In trying to build [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) with the TNonblockingServer (I hadn't before because it had [libevent](http://libevent.org/) dependencies), I've come across this error:

> error C2065: 'EWOULDBLOCK' : undeclared identifier

which is found in TNonblockingServer. EWOULDBLOCK is defined in a file called force_inc.h, but this file does not appear to be included in either the TNonblockingServer.h or the TNonblockingServer.cpp files.

I realize I could just `#include` the file and be done with it, but I was wondering if anyone with more experience with Thrift had encountered this issue before/knows if there is a more elegant way to fix this.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this occurs because I'm porting it over to VS2008, where the force_inc.h headers are not automatically included. In VS2010 and VS2012, this would not be the case.